# Possible to use variables and/or parameters with NSLocalizedString?

Tags: objective-c, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have tried using a variable as an input parameter to NSLocalizedString, but all I am getting back is the input parameter. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to use a variable string value as an index for NSLocalized string?

For example, I have some strings that I want localized versions to be displayed. However, I would like to use a variable as a parameter to NSLocalizedString, instead of a constant string. Likewise, I would like to include formatting elements in the parameter for NSLocalizedString, so I would be able to retrieved a localized version of the string with the same formatting parameters. Can I do the following:

Case 1: Variable NSLocalizedstring:

```
NSString *varStr = @"Index1";
NSString *string1 = NSLocalizedString(varStr,@"");
```

Case 2: Formatted NSLocalizedString:

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"This is an %@",@""),@"Apple"];
```

(Please note that the variable can contain anything, not just a fixed set of strings.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that a missing target entry is to blame. Just checking that my current build target includes the Localizable.string file solved the problem!

Answer (score 127):

If what you want is to return the localized version of "This is an Apple/Orange/whatever", you'd want:

```
NSString *localizedVersion = NSLocalizedString(([NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is an %@", @"Apple"]), nil);
```

(I.e., the nesting of `NSLocalizedString()` and `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` are reversed.)

If what you want is the *format* to be localized, but not the substituted-in value, do this:

```
NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"SomeFormat", nil), @"Apple"];
```

And in your `Localizable.strings`:

```
SomeFormat = "This is an %@";
```

Comment: Yeah, but the variable can contain anything, not just "apples" or "oranges". So I need to maintain flexibility.

Comment: Let me append my answer just in case.

Comment: Thank you very much; the appended answer is in fact what I was looking for -- and I hope you get an 'accept' checkbox soon.

Comment: You are not addressing the case 1: "Using variables and/or parameters with NSLocalizedString?". You can't do so and should use only const strings because localized strings should be translated before run time and string variable can be anything at runtime.

Answer (score 24):

I just want to add one very helpful definition which I use in many of my projects.

Inspired by androids possibility, I've added this function to my `header prefix` file:

```
#define NSLocalizedFormatString(fmt, ...) [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(fmt, nil), __VA_ARGS__]
```

This allows you to define a localized string like the following:

```
 "ExampleScreenAuthorizationDescriptionLbl"= "I authorize the payment of %@ to %@.";
```

and it can be used via:

```
self.labelAuthorizationText.text = NSLocalizedFormatString(@"ExampleScreenAuthorizationDescriptionLbl", self.formattedAmount, self.companyQualifier);
```

Answer (score 12):

For swift :

```
let myString = String(format: NSLocalizedString("I authorize the payment of %d ", comment: ""), amount)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
extension String {
    public var localizedString: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
    }

    public func localizedString(with arguments: [CVarArg]) -> String {
        return String(format: localizedString, arguments: arguments)
    }
}
```

Localizable.string:

```
"Alarm:Popup:DismissOperation:DeviceMessage" = "\"%@\" will send position updates on a regular basis again.";
"Global:Text:Ok" = "OK";
```

Usage:

```
let message = "Alarm:Popup:DismissOperation:DeviceMessage".localizedString(with: [name])
```

and

```
let title = "Global:Text:Ok".localizedString
```

Comment: This extensions cleans the code up so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one variable in your localized string can you use this solution:

In Localizable.strings

```
"winpopup" = "#name# wins a #type# and get #points# points(s)";
```

And use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString to insert the values

```
NSString *string = NSLocalizedString(@"winpopup", nil); //"#name# wins a #type# and get #points# points(s)"
NSString *foo = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#name#" withString:gameLayer.turn];
NSString *fooo = [foo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#type#" withString:winMode];
NSString *msg = [fooo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#points#" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", pkt]];
NSLog(@"%@", msg);
```

Comment: this seems very complicated. you can just use numbered placeholders:
`"exampleKey" = "%1$@ has bought %3$d apples and %2$d oranges."`
`[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"exampleKey", nil), @"Markus", 4, 3]`
This would output: `Markus has bought 3 apples and 4 oranges`.

Comment: And than go and explain these type of cryptographic strings to your translators around the world.

Comment: %1 or %2 is what must be used.

Answer (score 0):

Your ideas should work.  But if you are getting back the input parameter, that means that the input parameter was not found as a key in your Localizable.strings file.  Check the syntax and location of that file.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
NSMutableString *testMessage = [NSMutableString stringWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Some localized text", @"")];
testMessage = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[testMessage stringByAppendingString:someStringVariable]];
```